# Помогите сгруппировать массив

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив такого вида:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [numberRow] => 1
        [columnId] => 1
        [columnValue] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [numberRow] => 1
        [columnId] => 2
        [columnValue] => 10
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [numberRow] => 1
        [columnId] => 3
        [columnValue] => 245tgvae
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [numberRow] => 2
        [columnId] => 1
        [columnValue] => 2
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [numberRow] => 2
        [columnId] => 2
        [columnValue] => 20
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [numberRow] => 2
        [columnId] => 3
        [columnValue] => sg45t
    )
)
```

Мне нужно сгруппировать его по ключу numberRow,
чтобы он стал такого вида:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [numberRow] => 1
                [columnId] => 1
                [columnValue] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [numberRow] => 1
                [columnId] => 2
                [columnValue] => 10
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [numberRow] => 1
                [columnId] => 3
                [columnValue] => 245tgvae
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (

        [0] => Array
            (
                [numberRow] => 2
                [columnId] => 1
                [columnValue] => 2
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [numberRow] => 2
                [columnId] => 2
                [columnValue] => 20
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [numberRow] => 2
                [columnId] => 3
                [columnValue] => sg45t
            )

    )

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function _group_by($array, $key) {
    $resultArr = [];
    foreach($array as $val) {
        $resultArr[$val[$key]][] = $val;
    }
    return $resultArr;
}
```

входные данные:

```html
$test = [
 [
        'numberRow' => 1,
        'columnId' => 1,
        'columnValue' => 1
    ],

 [
        'numberRow' => 1,
        'columnId' => 2,
        'columnValue' => 10
    ],

 [
        'numberRow' => 1,
        'columnId' => 3,
        'columnValue' => '245tgvae'
    ],

 [
        'numberRow' => 2,
        'columnId' => 1,
        'columnValue' => 2
    ],

 [
        'numberRow' => 2,
        'columnId' => 2,
        'columnValue' => 20
    ],

 [
        'numberRow' => 2,
        'columnId' => 3,
        'columnValue' => 'sg45t'
    ]
];
```

Использование:

```
print_r(_group_by($test, 'numberRow'));
```

Пощупать тут: https://ideone.com/xd0pEt

Позаимствовано с https://stackoverflow.com/a/15102185/6104996

Comment: Всё правильно но не играйтесь `[],[],[]` и переменными одноимёными операторам. к примеру вы ничайно удалите `$` и не получите ошибки, а потом будете искать причину бага....

Comment: @Naumov не понял о чем вы? Оставляйте своё субъективное мнение про `[],[],[]` при себе пожалуйста

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, спасибо большое!

Comment: Вы учите человека объявлять массивы как `[]` вместо `array()`, а потом будете учить `<? ?>` вместо `<?php ?>` и т.д.

Comment: @Naumov Еще раз повторю, свое субъективное мнение оставьте при себе. Если вам религия не позволяет использовать то, что в введено `php` еще в версии `5.4` то это сугубо ваши моральные и духовные проблемы.

Comment: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/ru/coding-standard.coding-style.html Это не моё личное...

Comment: @Naumov ну да. теперь ваше и зенд фреймворка....эм...версии `1.12` с наличием версии `2.4`......Вы видимо что-то слишком буквально понимаете. Они не диктуют мировой стандарт. Это рекомендации по оформлению кода в **КОНКРЕТНОМ** фреймворке. В **ИХ** фреймворке. Другие фреймворки имеют свои правила оформления. Можете исследовать этот вопрос и убедиться в этом. Они не являются жестким требованием следовать этому правилу везде........Более того с их правилами можно очень поспорить. Одна только подстановка переменных в двойных кавычках чего стоит....А пока это всё ВАШИ ЛИЧНЫЕ нервы

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, полностью согласен с Вами!

я использую yii2 framework, и там уже заменили array() на [ ].
Я считаю, что нужно использовать новый синтаксис,
array() уже устарел

Comment: @Naumov, я использую `<?`, прекрасно себя чувствую.