# Поменять две переменные местами, не используя третью

Tags: php, соревнование

Задача об обмене двух *целочисленных* переменных значениями (без использования третьей) является одним из классических программистских ребусов.

Как сделать это в PHP, используя минимальное количество символов?

Критерий победы — минимальное количество символов. При прочих равных условиях ответ, опубликованный раньше, побеждает. Подведение итогов через 24 часа.

---

<sub>Пожалуйста, указывайте в ответе количество символов, чтобы проще было выявить победителя.</sub>

```js
function getAnswers(questionId, answer_filter, page) {
  return jQuery.ajax({
    url: '//api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/' + questionId + '/answers?page=' + page + '&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=activity&site=ru.stackoverflow&filter=' + answer_filter,
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true
  }).then(function(data) {
    if (data.has_more) {

      return getAnswers(questionId, answer_filter, page + 1).then(function(d) {
        return data.items.concat(d.items);
      })
    }
    return data.items;
  });
}

function getAuthorName(e) {
  return e.owner.display_name
}

function process(items) {

  return items.map(function(item) {
    var matched = item.body.match(/(\d+)[^\d]*?<\/h/);
    if (matched) {
      return {
        count: +matched[1],
        link: item.share_link,
        author: getAuthorName(item)

      };
    } else {
      return {
        count: 'N/A',
        link: item.share_link,
        author: getAuthorName(item)
      }
    }
  });
}

function sort(items) {
  return items.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.count == 'N/A') return 1;
    if (b.count == 'N/A') return -1;
    return a.count - b.count;
  })
}

function fillTemplate(sortedItems) {
  $('#leadership').append(sortedItems.map(function(item, index) {
    return $('<tr>').append($('<td>').html(index + 1))
      .append($('<td>').html(item.author))
      .append($('<td>').html(item.count))
      .append($('<td>').append($('<a>').attr('href', item.link).text('Link')));
  }));
  return sortedItems;
}

var QUESTION_ID = 540286,
  ANSWER_FILTER = "!4*SyY(4Kifo3Mz*lT",
  startPage = 1;
getAnswers(QUESTION_ID, ANSWER_FILTER, startPage)
  .then(process)
  .then(sort)
  .then(fillTemplate);
```

```css
#leadership {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
#leadership td,
#leadership th {
  padding: 5px;
}
#leadership th,
td:nth-child(3) {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Таблица лидеров</h1>
<table id="leadership">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Автор</th>
    <th>Количество символов</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

*Комментарий, о причине выбора победителя:*

Лидирующий ответ **@PashaPash** (0 символов) фактически не меняет переменных, поэтому не участвует в конкурсе.

Ответ от **@Naumov** (10 символов), вместо обмена переменных просто присваивает им новые значения. Ну и его длина не является постоянной, а зависит от значений переменных. Рассматривать этот ответ в рамках конкурсной программы я не буду.

Comment: А почему php? :(

Comment: @Qwertiy, потому что пора развивать сообщество в этом направлении. А то сейчас `PHP = кака-код`. Пора это менять, задавая хорошие, интересные вопросы. Гольф - один из путей.

Comment: Ааааа! Сортировка таблицы лидеров сбилась!

Comment: Таблицу @Grundy делал, так что это к нему вопрос =)

Comment: @VladD, поправил :)

Comment: а у меня вопрос. Переменные - чисто переменные или могут быть ссылки? Просто во 2 случае половина решений (если не больше) отвалится при `$y = &$x;`.

Comment: @pavel а тогда итогом должно быть что? дано `$x=1; $y=&$x;` итог должен быть `$y=1; $x=&$y;`?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну хотя бы значение не потерятся... Чтобы echo $x //1 echo $y //1 было.

Comment: @pavel а в чем тогда смысл перестановок и преобразования, если они, утрируя, имеют одинаковое значение изначально? Это разве не бессмысленно?

Comment: Вопросы интересные, однако больше с уклоном в спортивное программирование. Вот читаешь ответы и содрогаешься - "не, на продакшне я это точно использовать не буду": важен такой критерий как читаемость и понятность. Поэтому наряду со спортивными вопросами хорошо бы задавать также и вопросы которые имеют прямое отношение к реальным производственным задачам. А в целом идею поддерживаю.

Comment: @AK, ничего не имею против качественных вопросов по реальным задачам. Просто хотелось хоть как-то разбавить скучно-однообразные вопросы по PHP

Answer (score 33, accepted):

## PHP, 14 Символов

```
$a+=+$b-$b=$a;
```

[Рабочий пример](http://ideone.com/WJ2wG5) на IDEOne.

Comment: Любопытно, что выражение `$a+=$b-$b=$a;` - не работает

Comment: этот вариант настолько хакнутый, что надо проверить его работу в нескольких версиях PHP )

Comment: @Sergiks, стабильно работает везде, начиная с PHP@4.3.0. [Пруф](https://3v4l.org/qe0oP) (перед запуском стоит ткнуть галочку "_eol versions_")

Comment: Как-то неловко вышло: побеждает в конкурсе его организатор )

Comment: `$a-=-$b+$b=$a` от такого чуть меньше шаблон разрывает с ведущим +. А вообще, посмотрите на https://3v4l.org/fqV60/vld#tabs тут не создаётся дополнительная переменная. В сокращённой записи у вас 2 временные переменные. Это считается?

Comment: @pavel, Все, что не создает переменную явно соответствует формальным правилам (литералы, разумеется, не в счет). Как именно PHP выделяет внутри себя память - его дело. Более, того, что-то мне подсказывает, что для выражения `$a*$b+$c*$d` PHP внутри выделяет доп. память под каждое слагаемое.

Comment: @Sergiks, это случайно получилось. Ну и потом, в этом есть еще одна проблема: конкурс заканчивается сегодня, а собственный ответ я смогу принять только завтра.

Comment: Трюк, как я понимаю, заключается во времени вычисления аргументов минуса. Унарный плюс, образуя выражение, по всей видимости, первым разрешается в значение. И, видимо, это значение кладётся в неявную переменную. А поскольку минус получает свои аргументы по ссылке, без плюса не работает. Аааргх

Comment: @D-side звучит логично. Хотя это все-равно не объясняет, почему оператор с низким приоритетом (`=`) выполняется раньше операторов с высоким приоритетом (`-`).

Comment: А это потому что у них принципиально разные левые аргументы и группировка по выражениям происходит в неравных условиях. У `-` левый аргумент может быть любым выражением, а у `=` исключительно `lvalue`. Поэтому `=` слева от минуса выполнится позже него (т. к. справа от него может быть выражение, с операторами, с которыми он может конкурировать за приоритет), а справа  -- раньше (поскольку там `lvalue` должен быть непосредственно рядом, в упор).

Answer (score 31):

## PHP, 15 символов

```
$x^=$y^=$x^=$y;
```

Comment: Что за....??? =)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, круто правда? :-D

Comment: Очень. Я бы не додумался

Comment: Круто. Мне только list в голову всегда приходил

Comment: В плюсах так тоже работает, хотя и UB, формально. А вот на js и шарпе - не работает: `x` становится нулём.

Comment: известный приём) у него только один минус в С++ - если x и y  - ссылки на одну и туже переменную.

Comment: @pavel в PHP та же фигня: http://ideone.com/75m5je

Comment: А зачем сниппет?

Comment: @Qwertiy, это тест доступа к урлу вопроса из сниппета, скоро уберу :)

Comment: @Grundy, в моём хроме работает.

Comment: @Qwertiy, да вот, и в моей :-) а некоторые тут утверждают - что нет :)

Comment: Может кто объяснить как это работает вообще?

Comment: @Artur, последовательное применение xor с сохранением

Answer (score 13):

## PHP, <strike>25</strike> 20

```
list($a,$b)=[$b,$a];
```

Comment: У массивов есть короткий синтаксис =)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, это `[]`?

Comment: это же соревнование ;)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, пока больше никто не присоединился :-D

Comment: Похоже соревнование слишком простое

Comment: всегда такой подход только вижу

Comment: создаётся новая анонимная переменная массив же?

Comment: @Sergiks, создается _литерал_ массива. Это тоже самое, что и любое число: можно использовать литерал не создавая переменной

Comment: Но память-то съели : ) Массив в PHP весит много больше составляющих его переменных. Так можно и какой-нибудь ресурс создать, через свойства которого поменять переменные )

Comment: @Sergiks, память съели, тут вы правы. Но формально новая _переменная_ создана не была, значит все честно.

Comment: @Sergiks Кстати, при вычислении сложных выражений, вроде `$a*$b + $c*$d` дополнительная память тоже должна выделяться для вычисления каждого из слагаемых в отдельности.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev раз так, добавил себе вариант на 17: `$x=[$y,$y=$x][0];`

Answer (score 12):

## PHP, 15 Символов

```
$a=$a+$b-$b=$a;
```

Comment: @Sergiks, странно, у меня работает: http://ideone.com/OFStDr

Comment: Мой зевок, неправильно проверил. Действительно, **работает**.  Но [приоритет операторов](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) ведь ставит `+` и `–` раньше `=`! Почему это работает? : )

Comment: @Sergiks потому что приоритет только () ставят внутри скобок интерпритатор выполняет с начала. А так он интерпритирует с права на лево.

Comment: @Sergiks, это действительно интересно. Вот [тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.precedence.php) сказано, что у `=` действительно меньший приоритет, однако в замечании приведен пример, это опровергающий.

Comment: @Naumov, в документации к PHP сказано, что ассоциативность операторов не влияет на приоритет

Comment: @Naumov ерунду спороли. См. [документацию](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.precedence.php).

Comment: @Sergiks Да одинокий вечер после работы да жара

Comment: у всех методов с арифметическими операторами будут косяки на крупных числах (`PHP_INT_MAX`) и нулях `0`.

Comment: @Sergiks, у `list` - не должно быть

Comment: @DmitriySimushev `list()` – не арифметический оператор )  Я про ваше решение, своё с умножением и делением и Алексея Шиманского.

Answer (score 11):

Совсем альтернативный вариант:

Повторное присвоение значений переменным - в целом плохая идея.

- В плане читабельности кода - глядя на первое присвоение значений переменным тяжепо понять, чему ж они будут равны в конце метода. Особенно актуально для языков с нестрогой типизацией.
- В плане производительности - процессору гораздо удобнее просто начать брать значение из другого места, чем терять время на перекладывание значений из одного куска памяти в другой, и обратно.

Гораздо лучше просто заменить использование переменных в том коде, который расположен ниже места, где вы собирались вписать swap.

#### PHP, 0 символов

Comment: на мой взгяд очень спорное утверждение. Представьте что нам по какой-то причине нужно, что а было меньше b иначе - поменять местами. Тогда по вашему, нам нам нужно писать 2 ветви кода под `if/else` вместо обмена?

Comment: @pavel нет, конечно же. Надо выбрать минимум и максимум и дальше работать с этой парой.

Comment: А если, грубо говоря, у меня подряд идут три цикла `foreach` для вывода результата из бд в шаблон, в виде таблиц, но использую специально некоторую переменную `$nomer_po_porjadku` чтоб обозначить номер по порядку в них в первом столбце...... тогда нужно для трех таблиц и циклов три разные переменные заводить все равно, а не обнулять первую и переиспользовать?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский: В C++ локальные переменные внутри цикла таки не видны снаружи. Ну и да, переиспользовать переменные — плохая идея, потому что создаёт излишние зависимости между частями кода. Поверьте, компилятор умеет гораздо лучше нас с вами переиспользовать области памяти под ненужные переменные.

Comment: @VladD `локальные переменные внутри цикла таки не видны снаружи` ... либо я не понял, либо)) .. я говорю про `$nomerPp = 1; foreach($something as $item) { doSmth; echo '<div>номер: '.$nomerPp.'</div>'; $nomerPp++; }  $nomerPp = 1; foreach($anotherData as $item) { echo '<div>номер: '.$nomerPp.'</div>'; $nomerPp++; }  $nomerPp = 1; foreach($thirdArrayOfData as $item) { doSmth; echo '<div>номер: '.$nomerPp.'</div>'; $nomerPp++; }`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский: А, понял. Но по сути-то вам нужна каждый раз новая переменная, просто вы повторно используете старую? (И я бы разрефакторил этот код на три вызова вспомогательной функции, внутри каждой по счётчику.)

Comment: @VladD `просто вы повторно используете старую?`  - да... то есть смысл что-то новое создавать? ...`я бы разрефакторил этот код` - это лишь утрированный пример для сути) там внутри логика может быть разный и разметка. причем разметка не через `echo`выводится

Comment: @АлексейШиманский: Хороший код содержит как можно меньше зависимостей. Если у меня у переменной несколько различных смыслов, это плохо, потому что в какой-то момент это может клюнуть. Например, это вы сейчас уверены, что после первого цикла вам переменная не нужна, а завтра это может измениться. Больше зависимостей = хрупкий код.

Comment: @VladD у переменной смысл один номер по порядку,... я про код внутри цикла, различная структура данных, разное отображение, дополнительные условия и прочее.....вот. (кажется становится тут чат...)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский в C# кстати переменная $something реально переиспользовалась в прошлых версиях языка, что смешные баги при замыканиях на нее. Вот еще возможные спецэффекты при замыканиях и повторном использовании переменных: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/480645/

Comment: @АлексейШиманский и ваши пример - тоже отлично показывает почему переменные не стоит переиспользовать - достаточно потерять  один из $nomerPp = 1; при мерже (два человека допишет новый цикл, гит срезолвит  $nomerPp = 1; как совпадение, на выходе вы получите один сброс  $nomerPp = 1; и два цикла после него) - и все, приехали.

Comment: Это конкурс же а не вопрос

Comment: @PashaPash это называется руки из попы)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский это называется "ура! смержилось без конфликтов" :))

Comment: @Naumov да, и я надеюсь что дзен-метод с 0 символов его выиграет. или хотя бы займет почетное второе место.

Comment: @PashaPash во многих алгоритмах используется swap. Quick sort, например. Вы считаете, нужно переписывать такие алгоритмы или вовсе их не использовать?

Comment: @Trymount в quick sort меняются местами два элемента одного массива, а не значения двух переменных. не вижу причин его переписывать.

Comment: @PashaPash Хорошо. А если реализовывать защиту "от дурака". На вход подаются два индекса массива - с какого начинать и каким заканчивать. И пользователь "решил протестировать" и ввёл вначале больший индекс, а потом меньший. Вы предпочтёте вообще не выполнять задачу и попросите ввести заново или всё таки сделаете(границы то он указал) ?

Comment: @Trymount уже упоминалось выше - завести две новые переменные `int realStart = min(start, end); int realEnd = max(start; end)` и использовать их в коде. А не менять значения start и end местами.

Answer (score 10):

#### 17, 19, 23 и 42 символа

```
$x=[$y,$y=$x][0];                          // 17

$x/=$y=($x*=$y)/$y;                        // 19

eval("\$x=$y;\$y=$x;");                    // 23

extract(unpack("iy/ix",pack("i2",$x,$y))); // 42
```

Comment: помойму символы ' можно не использовать так как интежер значение

Comment: @Naumov уже тоже сообразил и убрал )

Comment: последний метод зачет )

Comment: @Naumov это магия числа [42](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_(number)#The_Hitchhiker.27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy) : )

Answer (score 8):

## PHP, 17 символов

```
$a=$a+$b-($b=$a);
```

Comment: Чуть-чуть не дожали

Comment: Сначала хотел отредактировать, но понял, что это не спортивно =)

Answer (score 8):

#### в общем для оригинальности 28 символов

```
extract(['b'=>$a,'a'=>$b]);
```

Comment: Я что-то не понял. Вы так яро пропагандировали `array()` вместо `[]`, а теперь сами нарушаете свои же принципы.  `Вы учите человека объявлять массивы как [] вместо array(), а потом будете учить <? ?> вместо <?php ?> и т.д` .......http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511800/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2/511803#comment621706_511803 ......позор вам!

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Вы обиделись и теперь нашли один `конкурсный` ответ. Подчёркиваю `соревнование,конкурс`. И пытаятесь меня этим по тролить :D Тогда вы получили downvote от меня по двум очевидным причинам это переменная `$array` и `[]`, два фактора могут привести к ошибке в коде. И удивительно вы заменили `array()` на `[]` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113256/group-array-values-based-on-key-in-php/15102185#15102185 ...

Comment: Я не использовал `$array` - раз...... я заменил array() на [] - ибо следую новшествам, а не плююсь слюной от этого как старый брюзга, и смысл от этого не изменится..... а то, что конкурсный вопрос или нет - значения не имеет, главное что вы не следуете тем самым правилам и стандартам, коими пытались или пытаетесь кормить остальных.... а здесь http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/540542/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-tetrisa-%D0%BD%D0%B0-php вообще гибрид...сами не определились.... это просто фу. мерзость и пакость.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Разница в том что:При `спортивном программирование` код живёт не большой промежуток времени, и над ним работаете только вы. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113256/group-array-values-based-on-key-in-php/15102185#15102185 смотрите в `foreach` а именно `foreach($array as $val) {`.

Comment: Это называется "переобулся" и "нет четкой позиции". Если вы считаете, что мир появился в результате большого взрыва, то входя в здание с верующими вы не должны резко становиться креоционистом.Если вы один ездите на *ВАЗ 2106*, то
чтоб съездить с друзьями куда-то она не станет *MERSEDES SLS 500*..A здесь http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/540542 у вас гермофродит. И не надо лепить еще какие смешные отмазы.....и да - если не можете отличить переменную `$array` от объявления массива `array()` то это опять же ваши личные внутренние проблемы.Ровно как и восприятие квадратных скобок в объявлении

Comment: И можете по пути избавления от проблемы восприятия массивов еще к каждому JS'нику , кто использует конструкции вида `$this = this;` лично подойти и сказать что он неправ! ))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский включите вот у вас есть переменная названная как оператор или функция к примеру `$return,$array,$var` где то в коде, вы работаете себе в ide или текстовом редакторе. Ну и нечайно удаляете знак `$` и воуля ошибки нет(потомучто для интерпретатора всё нормально) но работает не так как ожидаеться... А если брать названия не повторяющие функции или операторы вы получете ошибку `undefined constant`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Вы уже отходите от теме я backend программист я не знаю и знать не хочу js

Comment: Тема в том, что у вас проблемы с определением и восприятием, вот и все.......а `$this = this;` это отсыл к `$array = array();`.....а удалить случайно в коде можно все что угодно и когда угодно: и знак доллара и просто символ (в этом случае кого винить будете? еще кого-то?)) ). Тогда может вообще код не писать? Но т.к. случаются досадные неприятности - именно поэтому есть средства отладки и показ ошибок и глаза с мозгом которые видят ошибку и исправляют. А если криворукий и без мозга - то тогда ничего не поможет, никакие-либо именования следования какому-либо правилу

Comment: с `$return,$array,$var` все тоже самое... убрать доллар и будет либо ошибка о константе, либо синтаксическая ошибка, либо еще какая .... ведь `return return` к примеру вызовет ошибку, а никак не  сглотнет... `return = 12` вместо `$return = 12;` не кинет из функции а спокойно выдаст ошибку..... так что руки и мозг.......руки и мозг

Answer (score 8):

## PHP 7.1 (16 символов)

```
<?php
[$a,$b]=[$b,$a];
```

Comment: Хороший вариант. Но все равно слишком длинный (16 символов) :)

Comment: Зато работает не только с числами)

Answer (score 6):

#### Смеха ради, 76 символов

```
try{
    throw new Exception($b);
}catch(Exception $e){
    $b=$a;
    $a=$e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: А вот кстати, считается ли использование $e нарушением условий задачи?

Comment: Считается нарушением, да. Вы в явном виде заводите новую переменную для хранения исключения.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev тут вопрос несколько в другом. В случае try/catch у меня нет выбора, декларировать ли переменную в catch или нет, по сути - это конструкция языка. Философский вопрос в общем. :)

Comment: Оператор присваивания - тоже конструкция языка, с которой у вас нет выбора, декларировать переменную или нет. Как именно создавать переменную - не важно. Главное что их становится три.

Answer (score -4):

**PHP 10 символов**

допустим у нас 
`$a=1;$b=5;`

чтобы поменять их местами мы можем сделать так

`$a=5;$b=1;`

Comment: Ну это не серьезно и не спортивно. Представьте, что я тестирую ваш код вот с такими начальными условиями: `$a=rand(10000, 99999);$b=rand(10000, 99999);`. Работает метод?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev в условие нет условия что нельзя их поменять руками. Это смекалка же! Да и ответ более шуточный. Да и о методах тестирование ни чего в условиях нет.

Comment: Про цифры 5 и 1 в условии тоже ничего нет. И вообще, джентльмены себя так не ведут. Не стоит подавать плохой пример окружающим =)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev Чувство юмора, и нетрадиционное мышление, это хороший пример окружающим. Я так считаю :D

Comment: Ну, вы почти пришли к идеальному решению! Если из значения равны, то вообще делать ничего не надо.

Comment: @D-side 0 символов:D

Comment: Вот вы смеётесь, а в IOCCC в 1994 участвовала пустая программа, как заявлено "выводящая свой исходный код".